# Python dict-like data structure where any element of a set is a key to that set

Tags: python, data-structures

Is there an already-implemented data structure in Python that's somewhat like a dictionary but where the values are a set/dict (having keys would be preferrable but if there's something like this that already exists that doesn't have keyed elements it's not a showstopper) and where any element in the set/dict serves as a key to find the set/dict? This would work in the case that all sets involved were disjoint.

Concrete example:
I'm connecting 8-bit vector values to characters and to names and I want to be able to search for one of those things and get back the other 2 pieces of information from the 3rd:

```
class group_lookup_dict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.groups = []

    def add(self, new_group):
        self.groups.append(new_group)

    def lookup(self, key):
        for group in self.groups:
            if key in group.values():
                return group

class group_lookup_dict: # edit: this one's better
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_dict = {}

    def add(self, new_group):
        if type(new_group) is dict:     # it's a dict
            iterator = new_group.values()
        else:                           # it's a set (or list, tuple, etc...)
            iterator = iter(new_group)
        for val in iterator:
            self.main_dict[val] = new_group

    def lookup(self, key):
        return self.main_dict[key]

my_group_lookup_dict = group_lookup_dict()

example_group = {"char": "&", "bits": "00100110", "name": "CHAR_AMPERSAND"} # https://mil.ufl.edu/3744/docs/lcdmanual/characterset.html
my_group_lookup_dict.add(example_group)

print(my_set_lookup_dict.lookup("&"))
>>> {'char': '&', 'bits': '00100110', 'name': 'CHAR_AMPERSAND'}
# also acceptable would be: {'&', '00100110', 'CHAR_AMPERSAND'}
```

Edit: The above code does exactly what I want. I'm merely curious if there's a somewhat popular datastructure that works similarly that I can use without having to either remember what file that class definition is saved in or write it over again when a simple...

```
from collections import my_cool_group_lookup_dict
```

...would suffice.

Comment: You can do some processing on the dictionary, and thus construct an "index" structure that maps these values to the added "group".

Comment: I don't follow @WillemVanOnsem... can you elaborate?

Comment: Another problem here might be that if the group is *mutable*, we do not get notified if the values change.

Comment: An interesting idea. There is nothing in stdlib, but there might be something on PyPI that you could install.